# Comparing 2 diffirent certain reaction count on a discord message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I'm making a poll command but I don't know how to see the count of a certain reaction there are, and I want to compare 2 different reaction's count.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I have the embed of the poll sorted, i just dont know how to count reactions, and check how many of each one there are.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You should look at this.

Comment: Are you looking for like an output of the current winning vote?

Comment: **Are you looking for like an output of the current winning vote?** Yes, i am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough but as I know you can get a specific emoji with this

```py
@client.command()
async def random_command(ctx):
    emoji = "\N{HAPPY PERSON RAISING ONE HAND}"
    reaction = get(ctx.message.reactions, emoji=emoji)
```

This should work for certain emojis.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.